# Get position of element in collection filtered by a condition

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I need to get the index (position) of an element when filtered by a condition.

Here is the code to filter by condition:

```
var rank =  await _dbContext.VwJobSupplierWithScores
    .OrderBy(x => x.CalculatedSpendCurrencyJob) 
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.JobId == jobId && x.SupplierKey == supplierKey);
```

I need to get the position of the element in the collection that returns before `.FirstOrDefaultAsync`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
var rankPair =  await _dbContext.VwJobSupplierWithScores
    .OrderBy(x => x.CalculatedSpendCurrencyJob)
    .Select((x, i) => new { item = x, index = i })
    .Where(pair => pair.item.JobId == jobId && pair.item.SupplierKey == supplierKey)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

var rank = rankPair.item;
int index = rankPair.index;
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `(item: x, index: i)` rather than `(item = x, index = i)` ?

Comment: @MatthewWatson `An expression tree may not contain a tuple literal` with  `(item: x, index: i)`

Comment: Not translatable to the SQL `Select` overload.

Comment: @EugeneSukh Apparently, ValueTuple doesn't work well with EF. You can use an anonymous object instead.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, that was an oversight. I switched to an anonymous type anyway.